# Button text in firefox moves to the right on clicking

Tags: html, css, firefox

I can't figure out which css property in Firefox's User Stylesheet is causing the button text to shift to the right when clicking.

I'm trying to remove/overwrite this feature.

```
<button>Why am I moving to the right?</button>
```

This doesn't happen on Chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/xd3tp06n/

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in a [mcve] here on Stack Overflow. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do almost everything JSFiddle can.

Comment: That's all the necessary code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's padding (in this case [padding-inline-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start)):

```css
button:active:hover,
input[type="color"]:active:hover,
input[type="reset"]:active:hover,
input[type="button"]:active:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active:hover {
  padding-block-start: 0px;
  padding-inline-end: 7px;
  padding-block-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 9px;
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: ButtonFace;
}
```

^ Taken from `view-source:resource://gre-resources/forms.css`